# Designing a generic unstructured data store

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-structures

The project I have been given is to store and retrieve unstructured data from a third-party. This could be HR information – User, Pictures, CV, Voice mail etc or factory related stuff – Work items, parts lists, time sheets etc. Basically almost any type of data.

Some of these items may be linked so a User many have a picture for example. I don’t need to examine the content of the data as my storage solution will receive the data as XML and send it out as XML. It’s down to the recipient to convert the XML back into a picture or sound file etc. The recipient may request all Users so I need to be able to find User records and their related “child” items such as pictures etc, or the recipient may just want pictures etc.

My database is MS SQL and I have to stick with that. My question is, are there any patterns or existing solutions for handling unstructured data in this way.

I’ve done a bit of Googling and have found some sites that talk about this kind of problem but they are more interested in drilling into the data to allow searches on their content. I don’t need to know the content just what type it is (picture, User, Job Sheet etc).

---

To those who have given their comments:

The problem I face is the linking of objects together. A User object may be added to the data store then at a later date the users picture may be added. When the User is requested I will need to return the both the User object and it associated Picture. The user may update their picture so you can see I need to keep relationships between objects. That is what I was trying to get across in the second paragraph. The problem I have is that my solution must be very generic as I should be able to store anything and link these objects by the end users requirements. EG: User, Pictures and emails or Work items, Parts list etc. I see that Microsoft has developed ZEntity which looks like it may be useful but  I don’t need to drill into the data contents so it’s probably over kill for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [Microsoft Zentity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/zentity/) since version 1, and whilst it is excellent a storing huge amounts of structured data and allowing (relatively) simple access to the data, if your data structure is likely to change then recreating the 'data model' (and the regression testing) would probably remove the benefits of using such a system.

Another point worth noting is that Zentity requires filestream storage so you would need to have the correct version of SQL Server installed (2008 I think) and filestream storage enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Since you deal with XML, it's not an unstructured data. Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or later has XML column type that you can use.

Now, if you don't need to access XML nodes and you think you will never need to, go with the plain `varbinary(max)`. For your information, storing XML content in an XML-type column let you not only to retrieve XML nodes directly through database queries, but also **validate** XML data against schemas, which may be useful to ensure that the content you store is valid.

Don't forget to use `FILESTREAM`s (SQL Server 2008 or later), if your XML data grows in size (2MB+). This is probably your case, since voice-mail or pictures can easily be larger than 2 MB, especially when they are Base64-encoded inside an XML file.

Comment: ... I was just typing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is quite freeform and changable, your best bet is to put it on a plain old file system not a relational database.  By all means store some meta-information in SQL where it makes sense to search through structed data relationships but if your main data content is not structured with data relationships then you're doing yourself a disservice using an SQL database.

The filesystem is blindingly fast to lookup files and stream them, especially if this is an intranet application.  All you need to do is share a folder and apply sensible file permissions and a large chunk of unnecessary development disappears.  If you need to deliver this over the web, consider using WebDAV with IIS.

A reasonably clever file and directory naming convension with a small piece of software you write to help people get to the right path will hands down, always beat any SQL database for both access speed and sequential data streaming.  Filesystem paths and file names will always beat any clever SQL index for data location speed.  And plain old files are the ultimate unstructured, flexible data store.

Use SQL for what it's good for.  Use files for what they are good for.  Best tools for the job and all that...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any pattern for this implementation. Store all your data in a BLOB entry. Read from it when required and then send it out again.

Yo would probably need to investigate other infrastructure aspects like periodically cleaning up the db to remove expired entries.

Maybe i'm not understanding the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

So am I right if I say that all you need to store is a blob of xml with whatever binary information contained within? Why can't you have a users table and then a linked(foreign key) table with userobjects in, linked by userId?

Comment: I can’t have a Users table as the data may not be anything to do with Users. You are correct that I can store a blob of XML which is “something” that I’ve been sent. I then need to maintain links between parent and child objects. My original question was is there a recommended way of doing this but it looks like there isn’t. I’m going to see what is done in the Zentity stuff produced by the Microsoft Research people. Their work may help in getting a good scalable design.

Comment: @Retrocoder : What types of parent object do you store? Is it an unlimited variety or limited?

Comment: I’m looking to create an agnostic data store so the parent objects could be anything, as could the child objects. The end user will need to define a “type” for each object which would just be a string name “User”, “Parts List”, “CV”, “Sound bite” etc. They will also have to define a relationship (not sure how) so that I know that objects of type “X” are parents of object type “Y” and objects of type “Z” have no children. My solution must be very generic to handle any condition.